# Azure cli says not registered in namespace

Tags: macos, azure, azure-cli

I am able to create Linux VMs in Azure using the web portal and happily SSH in, but I have scoured the documentation and am unable to assemble a CLI command that will work, for example:

`$ azure vm quick-create -M newkey.pub -g myresgrp -Q CoreOS --name gaiusvm1 -u gaius -l westeurope -y Linux`

This fails with:

```
error:   The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Compute'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to register subscriptions.
error:   Error information has been recorded to /Users/gaius/.azure/azure.err
error:   vm quick-create command failed
```

I have verified that the subscription my CLI sees with `azure account list` is the Pay-As-You-Go one that the web portal sees also.

Per the instructions on the page in the error I have done:

```
$ azure provider register Microsoft.Compute
```

Which fails with:

```
error:   Namespace Microsoft.Compute Registration took too long to complete
error:   Error information has been recorded to /Users/gaius/.azure/azure.err
error:   provider register command failed
```

What is the CLI doing differently from the portal, I assumed they'd actually be calling the same services under the covers, and how can I register in this and any other namespace?

Comment: You can create an ARM virtual machine in Azure Portal, and the portal will register for you. This error happens when you are using a new subscription. Actually, you can just wait for a while after you run `azure provider register Microsoft.Compute`. The Registration does take some time, and the timeout for Azure CLI is just too short.

Comment: @JackZeng that was it - please make this an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Error Happens when you are using a new subscription. The simplest way to fix this is to create an ARM virtual machine in Azure Portal, and the portal will register `Microsoft.Compute` for you.

If you are using `azure provider register Microsoft.Compute` to register the namespace, you might get an error telling that "Registration took too long to complete". This is because the Registration does take some time, and the timeout for Azure CLI is just too short. But, don't worry. The namespace will be registered eventually in a few minutes. And, you can check the registration state with the following command.

```
azure provider show Microsoft.Compute
```

You will see something like this.

```
info:    Executing command provider show
+ Getting provider information
data:    Namespace: Microsoft.Compute
data:    Registration state: Registering
....
```

After a few minutes, when the Registration state becomes Registered, you will be able to create ARM virtual machines with Azure CLI.

Comment: By the way tho' the portal *doesn't* seem to have registered for me; I could always click to create a VM, only the CLI was failing in this way. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Do you have multiple subscriptions for your tenant? If you can create an ARM Virtual Machine with Azure Portal, you should be able to create one with Azure CLI. Make sure you are using the same subscription, and make sure that you are creating Resource Manager VM, not the classic VM.

Comment: Nope only the one, that's what makes this so weird!